# Differences in word order?

Tags: word-order, writing-style, dependent-clause

The independent clause, “He is carrying a heavy load”, might be connected with a dependent clause of varying order:

- most of which is to be consumed.
- which most of, is to be consumed.
- of which, most is to be consumed.

What are the reasons for the variation? Is it simply a question of style or preference? Is there a *right* answer?

Comment: The second variant sounds ghastly. I'm happier with the first than the third (which needs to lose the shown comma).

Comment: I think I meant to write the second variant as “which of most is to be consumed.” Does that make it any more palatable?

Comment: Getting even worse.

Comment: How does word arrangement affect clause quality?

Comment: Reasonably set patterns arise (though they do often evolve). Other forms do not, and sound unnatural (and are often confusing). Even worse getting.